# Rails: sign_out current_user not working?

Tags: javascript, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to logout a user session after idle time. I have a controller action in `sessions_controller.rb` with the below code.

```
  def inactivity
    flash.now[:alert] = 'Logged out due to inactivity.'
    flash.keep(:alert)
    sign_out current_user
    head :ok
  end
```

below is the relevant js code which gets triggered after idle time and redirects the user to the sign out page

```
Session.inactivity().then(function() {
 localStorage.removeItem(idleTimeCaptureKeyName);
 Turbolinks.visit('/users/sign_in');
}).catch(function(err) {
});
```

Session.inactivity code is below

```
  const inactivity = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/inactivity',
        method: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token',$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
        },
        success: function(res) {
          resolve(true);
        },
        error: function(err) {
          reject(false);
        }
      })
    });
  }
```

I am seeing a strange issue where possibly `sign_out current_user` is not working. I see sporadically the user is redirected to home page with a message `you are already signed in`.

I am unable to reproduce the issue consistently. below is my question

1. what scenario could cause this and how can i reproduce and fix this

Comment: Could you provide more information. If you get `you are already signed in` then you won't sign you yet. How do you sing out the users? What the `Session.inactivity()` do? It's really do request to the server?

Answer (score 0):

If the `Session.inactivity()` do request to server you have to make sure that user  really logged out and you get proper response. I suppose that some times the `then` runs earlier then you get the response.

Comment: Hi @m.seliverstov thanks for your reply, i have updated the question